# How to auto import the necessary classes in Android Studio with shortcut?

Tags: android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just switch to Android Studio 0.5.1, and the things going so slow here, because nothing works in the regular way...

How do I import the necessary classes with shortcut?

I mean like this ones?

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: I found that its quite the shift from Eclipse, but after you get familiar with it, its much more powerful.

Comment: Please check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34523883/2826147)

Answer (score 134, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Auto Import -> Java and make the below things:

Select Insert imports on paste value to All

Do tick mark on *Add unambigious imports on the fly option* and "Optimize imports on the fly*

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "Android Studio" -> Preferences -> Settings for OSX

Comment: Option in Mac Android Studio 1.2: Android Studio Menu --> Preferences --> Editor --> General --> Auto Import

Comment: This is current: Mac Android Studio 1.2: Android Studio Menu --> Preferences --> Editor --> General --> Auto Import –  user23 Jun 16 at 8:23

Comment: Shortcut for Shortcut is... Just Press **CTRL+ALT+S** and Search String `Auto Import`, **Checked** and **OK**

Comment: For Latest Version of android Studio Go to File -> Settings-> Editor -> General -> Auto Import .

Answer (score 35):

Go on the missing declaration with cursor and press alt+enter
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed competence!

Comment: Thanks for this. Everyone else suggests the setting to enable auto import but that only works when there is no conflict, when there is you need this.

Answer (score 17):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to optimize imports

Answer (score 9):

On my Mac Auto import option was not showing it was initially hidden

```
Android studio ->Preferences->editor->General->Auto Import
```

and then typed in searched field **auto** then auto import option appeared.
And now auto import option is now always shown as default in `Editor->General`.
hopefully this option will also help others.
See attached screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 9):

To import classes on the fly :

On OSX press <kbd>Alt(Option)</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 4):

**File -> Settings -> Keymap** 
Change keymaps settings to your previous IDE to which you are familiar with

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Eclipse's keyboard shortcuts: just go on preferences > keymap and choose Eclipse from the drop-down menu. And all your Eclipse shortcuts will be used in here.

Answer (score 3):

On Windows with Android Studio 1.5.1 :
File --> Settings --> Editor --> General --> Auto Import

[image]