# Android Studio import class shortcut

Tags: android, android-studio

I've looked at [How to auto import the necessary classes in Android Studio with shortcut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272524/how-to-auto-import-the-necessary-classes-in-android-studio-with-shortcut) but it doesn't help.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> does nothing.

[image]

When I press alt+enter I get the following:

[image]

I do not want this, I wish for it to appear as a normal import at the top of the file.

What are these shortcuts called in Android Studio? This program makes it complicated to edit such simple shortcuts.

I also have auto-imports, but it isn't working:

[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Finally after hours of trail and error the following settings is what fixed it:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help :-)

Comment: Thumbs up!! Thanx!

Answer (score 5):

Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> on Mac will open a dialog to choose which library to import.

Answer (score 1):

check this link for detail ans
https://stackoverflow.com/a/37362700/3288890

or

> goto file -> setting select keymap and search for auto import and add keyboard short cut

[image]