# Import class in android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, keyboard-shortcuts, android-shortcut

I am new in Android Studio. I don't know **how to import a class in Android Studio**, using shortcut key?

I have used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> like Eclipse but it's not working in Android Studio.

Any solution ?

Comment: Alt+enter in android studio

Comment: If you use `OS X`, `option`+`return` instead.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look everytool has its own different ways

for import you can **use** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>

here is [link](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html) for **shortcuts** for android studio

for easiness you can do this , you can use **Eclipse shortcuts in Androidstudio**

```
File -> Settings -> Keymap -> <Choose Eclipse from Keymaps dropdown>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> keys to import.

Comment: @Er.Rakesh working but i cannot getting options like Import,fix project , etc etc  ..

Comment: if single import available then it will add or if multiple option will available then it will give option to choose import

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>Enter</kbd> in android studio .

**Alt + Enter key binding**

> For quick fixes to coding errors, the IntelliJ powered IDE implements
>   the Alt + Enter key binding to fix errors (missing imports, variable
>   assignments, missing references, etc) when possible, and if not,
>   suggest the most probable solution.

Please read **[Android Studio Tips and Tricks](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/sdk/installing/studio-tips.html)**

Answer (score 1):

1. step 1 > click on the red error code
2. step 2 > **Alt + Enter** and you will get a list of recommendations to solve the error
3. step 3 > if "**import class**" is available in the list, select it by pressing enter again and the class will import automatically

Answer (score 1):

Also, it's worth noting that you can auto-import classes in Android Studio. Just search for it in Settings and check off "Add unambiguous imports on the fly".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10723714)

Comment: Okay. I'm very new to Stack Overflow, so where should a post like this have gone instead?

Answer (score 0):

1.step 1 -> Where red error code is showing click on that

2.step 2 -> Now you use ALT+Enter key to import.

Follow this link its useful for you to find shortcut key for android studio :

http://javapapers.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Android-Studio-Shortcuts-You-Need-the-Most.pdf