# How to auto import missing class in the latest android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am following the basic tutorials in the Android Developer official site.
And there's a part that I cant get to work.

The instruction said if you want to import the missing class just use `ALT + ENTER` on the top part of the class.

When I do that it wont import the missing classes. Instead its just viewing the `Create Test` option only.

I'm new in Android development I hope you can help me.

Comment: Just check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272524/how-to-auto-import-the-necessary-classes-in-android-studio-with-shortcut

Comment: Please check this link [AUTO IMPORT ON FLY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Auto import will only work if the missing class in question is underlined. So if you see a class in red, click on the screen somewhere close to the class to adjust the cursor position and then try <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> once the class name is underlined.

Another option is to auto complete when typing the class name (which can be accomplished via <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or <kbd>TAB</kbd>, sorry muscle memory makes me forget which...) This will automatically import the appropriate class.

If you are using a third party library and this isn't appearing properly, make sure you add a compile statement for that library in your gradle build file.

Comment: Ok thanks. I remembered I changed my import into `auto import`. So If my setting is in `auto import` is it still necessary to use `ALT + ENTER` command to import missing classes? By the way there are no red lines in my code. So I think its fine and the other is in `variable never used`

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of your screen? I'm not sure I understand what your issue is.