# Importing a list of classes to a project on Android studio

Tags: android, class

I'm trying to import a list of classes (.class files ) into my blank activity android project ( on Android Studio)
All I've done is copy these files to `/libs` in the directory of the project 
how can I import these classes to MainActivity.java to use them ?

Comment: Does this helps you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16615038/what-is-the-shortcut-to-auto-import-all-in-android-studio or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272524/how-to-auto-import-the-necessary-classes-in-android-studio-with-shortcut

Comment: No, as I see, I need to convert these classes to one Jar file,

Comment: I am unable to convert it through the command line, I should add jar to the environment variables . but how? @XoseSanchez

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is change package in those classes to your package.
For example, in class `imported.class` find first line and edit `package` to match your package - in this example `package com.mycompany.exampleapp.libs;`.
Than, you can work with your class as usual:

```
MyClass object;  
object = new MyClass();  
...  
...
```