# How to import generated class from Apollo Client (GraphQL) in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, apollo, apollo-android

I'm new to Android studio and want to write a small example app with GraphQL and the [Apollo Client](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-android).

I've successfully setup my build environment and the automated code generation. Here's a screenshot of the file structure, `build/generated/apollo/AllPostsQuery` is the class that was autogenerated based on `src/main/graphql/AllPosts.graphql`:

[image]

My only issue now is that I don't know how to import the `AllPostsQuery` class into my `MainActivy`.

I simply tried:

```
import AllPostsQuery;
```

but that doesn't work:

> Can not resolve symbol `AllPostsQuery`.

Do I need to add any prefixes to the import path?

Comment: See here how to let AS auto-import classes for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22272524/how-to-auto-import-the-necessary-classes-in-android-studio-with-shortcut

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I believe my auto-import is already setup, it did work for all the other classes (I didn't write a single import myself so far). https://imgur.com/VcVFXp4 any other ideas?

Comment: You should set up a package directory tree under `graphql/`. The generated code will go into that package. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-graphql/tree/v0.3/Trips/CW/StaticList).

Comment: ah great that worked @CommonsWare! if you add this as an actual answer I'll mark it as accepted and you get your points :)

Comment: Were you able to resolve the ANDROID_HOME issue?

Comment: @cricket_007 no unfortunately not! I've just started a fresh project now where the build works... I still can't run the sample project from the apollo-android repo...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way your project is structured in the question, you have your GraphQL document and the schema JSON directly in `graphql/`. That will result in your generated Java class not being put into a package. That's probably not what you want.

Apollo-Android takes the approach that is used for some other forms of source code (Java, AIDL, etc.), and uses a package directory tree. In [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-graphql/tree/v0.3/Trips/CW/StaticList) (from [this book](https://commonsware.com/GraphQL/)), I have my GraphQL document and schema JSON in `graphql/com/commonsware/graphql/trips/api`. As a result, my generated Java classes are in the `com.commonsware.graphql.trips.api` package.

So, set up a series of subdirectories for whatever Java package you want your generated code to go into, and move your GraphQL document and schema JSON there.